# Alexa incorrectly spoke invocation name

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I had Alexa app.The problem is Alexa pronouncing the invocation name incorrectly. To fix the invocation name inside the script we can make use of SSML but on invocation name it only need the plain text. Does Alexa have pronunciation option as like google has. or Is there any other way where we can fix the pronunciation of the invocation name.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. Anyways contact Alexa at https://developer.amazon.com/support/contact-us?subjectCategory=ALEXA and ask them on how to proceed. Maybe they can manually change pronunciation from their end!